Google App Script custom sidepanel header
I'm working on a Google Docs add-on using Google Apps Script components, and I need to customize the sidebar header with a specific background color and height. Using HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar'), I can set only the title, and the header is located outside the component's iframe, so I'm unable to make changes. However, I've seen that the Zoho Notebook workspace add-on has a yellow header with an additional dropdown menu, suggesting that it's possible to modify the header. How can I achieve a similar level of customization?


Instead of creating an Editor add-on, you might need to create a Workspace add-on. A Workspace Add-on uses the Card Service for the user interface instead of the methods to show a custom menu and dialogs / sidebar used in an Editor Add-on.
Please bear in mind that each add-on type has its capabilities and limitations.
Resources

https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/overview

